# Is it ok to use one ViewModel for multiple activities?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

I am building a work management app and trying to implement Android architecture components. I have one activity for viewing details about a task and then multiple activities to edit that task. Since all data in all these activities will be the same and those activities will be frequently opened one after another with the same data, is it ok for me to share one ViewModel for all of them, or should I create separate ViewModel for all of them? Thanks! :)

Comment: You won't be able to find a ViewModelStore that makes sense to share the ViewModel, unless you make it yourself as a singleton I guess, in which case `onCleared()` will never happen.

Answer (score -1):

You can use shared view model of activity for fragments. For example, you have `ItemActivity` and it hosts `ItemFragment` for item preview and `ItemEditFragment` for editing. You can get *activity level* view model in `onCreate()` callback of fragments:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val vm = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ItemViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
}
```

More over, this approach can help you [implement master-detail model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) for wide screens.

You should note, single view model for different types of view (e.g. preview, edit) may be harder to maintenance than independent view models for each view.